# Absolute paths in Mac and Windows

Tags: php

I have a PHP program that uses dom->save() with an absolute path.

```
Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/feed/ultrafeed.xml
```

I will be using this on both Mac and Windows machines so is there a way to create a path that is either relative or independent of the user's platform?

Comment: use directory separator.

Comment: It doesn't work with relative paths?

Comment: What you show is a relative path.  What are you wanting?

Comment: AFAIK there's no standard Applications directory in Windows, and you shouldn't be saving user data to that folder on OS X anyway.

Comment: The path shown is an absolute path but is a local path. Now if I switched to Windows I'd have to change this path even if i had XAMP and a folder named feed. My question was more swung towards is there a way to translate depending on platform?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php   will return the current working directory, maybe thats helpful

Comment: What is the purpose of this file is it included in distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes by using `realpath()`

Try this, for example you have a relative path:

```
$path = "feed/ultrafeed.xml";
$path = realpath($path);
echo $path;
```

This will give you `C:\real\path\feed\ultrafeed.xml` on Windows
And `/real/path/feed/ultrafeed.xml` on Unix.

Comment: This looks very promising, will try ASAP

Comment: To use relative paths add the `__DIR__` constant to `realpath()` `realpath(__DIR__ . "/feed/ultrafeed.xml");`

Comment: Is there a way to go up the directory tree as I'm trying to use realpath() within an includes file in order to point to a folder in another directory

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'path' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'to'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'file';`
```

If you know where it is relative to the current file use `__DIR__` instead f `$_SERVER`